# Inject Javascript into Chrome with Android App?

Tags: android

Is there a way for an Android app to inject Javascript into a web page that's opened by Chrome?

The app would need to essentially run in the background 24/7 and startup with the phone as well.

We have a browser extension for Chrome that does similar.  Basically it's just a content script that's added into every web page browsed by the user.

I couldn't find if there's a way to do that with an Android app or if it's impossible to modify web pages opened in Chrome.

Comment: "Is there a way for an Android app to inject Javascript into a web page that's opened by Chrome?" -- no, unless there is a security flaw in Chrome somewhere. Malware authors would be very pleased if this were possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for taking the time to answer.  I've created a new question that explains exactly what I'm trying to do, in case there's a different way it can be done on Android.  If you have time:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461290/how-to-redirect-bad-sites-with-android-app